# How to call a function that depends on the input choice?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to call 2 functions that depend on the input choice in the selector.

I tried with this sample code but I get an error when compiling

```
[long , short]  = choice_opt == 'option 1' ? function_1(obv)  : function_2(obv)
```

And here is the error I got:

```
Cannot call 'operator ?:' with argument 'expr2'='call 'function_2(obv)' ([series bool, series bool])'. An argument of '[series bool, series bool]' type was used but a 'input bool' is expected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused due to the tuples, which are limited in Pine Script. One workaround is to split the tuple that is returned by the function to separate functions, and it will work. For example, this code works perfectly fine:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true)

choice_opt_long = input.string("option 1", "Options", ["option 1", "option 2"])
choice_opt_short = input.string("option 1", "Options", ["option 1", "option 2"])

function_1_long() =>
    long1 = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
    long1

function_2_long() =>
    long2 = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 20), ta.sma(close, 40))
    long2

function_1_short() =>
    short1 = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
    short1

function_2_short() =>
    short2 = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 20), ta.sma(close, 40))
    short2


long = choice_opt_long == 'option 1' ? function_1_long()  : function_2_long()
short = choice_opt_short == 'option 1' ? function_1_short()  : function_2_short()


if (long)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

if (short)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned new things

Answer (score 1):

```
option_ = input.string('option1', options=['option1','option2'])

function_(type,arg1,arg2)=>
    long_1= na
    if type=='option1'
        {do stuff}
        long_1 := value or bool
    long_2 =na
    if type=='option2'
        {do stuff}
        long_2 := value or bool

    [return1,return2]


[long_1,long_2] = function_(option_,x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned new things